Syntactic analysis of why wh-island violations should be ungrammatical yet are commonly used
This is a type of sentence which I found myself often verging on uttering, then pausing when I realized it wasn't grammatical, and trying to find a simple fix to express the same idea with the same fluidity:

You can see in the screenshot below a spotlight suggestion that I don't understand why it shows up.

The idea is that "I don't understand..." is a relative clause, so there shouldn't be an "it" in it. However, in English at least, you cannot say "that I don't understand why shows up" (although it would be interesting to consider if such a construct could become grammatical, with use?)
I believe this is called wh-island violation, and I am very interested to know if there are languages where these kinds of constructions would actually be possible.
I have encountered a little bit of reference materials to check up on like John Robert Ross or a paper like this.
I would like a simple beginner's explanation of why this construction is ungrammatical yet seems to occur so frequently and seems to have an "expressive need". Thanks.

Given that your profile says you’re in Copenhagen and/or Stockholm, I’m a little surprised that you ask for languages where such constructions would be possible, because they’re perfectly normal and grammatical in both Danish and Swedish. Granted, they’re more common when there is a subject different from the subordinator (as in ‘… that I don’t understand why I’m getting’), but examples where the subordinator is also subject can be found (e.g., “… som jeg ikke forstår hvor kommer fra” would work in Danish).

I was about to comment that Korean allows such sentences - but I found that the paper you linked already contains such an example in Korean!

Arguably if a construction occurs frequently, then it is not ungrammatical, but the grammar is wrong. I'll get my coat...

This often happens when a speaker is too far into an utterance to say it in a standard way and often call for: the reason for which or similar workarounds.
